# The type does not include any accessible constructors WPF - no window application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

I'm using [this](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) package to create and use notify icon, which means I have no Windows in my app just `ResourceDictionary` and `ViewModel`

It all is working fine and well until I changed my constructor to accept an interface using DI framework(I'm using **Autofac** extension to PRISM [Prism.Autofac]).

If I adding back the parameterless constructor everything works just fine

Should I even use Autofac is is overkill? how can I do the DI?

Notes

- im using **PRISM** as my MVVM framework
- The Interface is located in another project
- I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269166/how-not-to-use-the-default-constructor-using-the-mvvm-ui-pattern), [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/mvvm-instantiation-approaches), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337649/wpf-the-viewmodel-type-does-not-contain-any-accessible-constructors) and the
  [`ObjectDataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) documentation and could not find any solution

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private TaskbarIcon notifyIcon;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();

            notifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");          
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            notifyIcon.Dispose();
            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }
```

**App.xaml**

```
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="NotifyIconResources.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

**NotifyIconResources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
                    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WatchDog"
                    xmlns:interface="clr-namespace:ServiceControllerLibary;assembly=ServiceControllerLibary"
                    >
    <local:ServiceControllerWorkerStatusToIconConverter x:Key="ServiceControllerWorkerStatusToIconConverter"/>

    <ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Show Window" />
        <MenuItem Header="Hide Window" />
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
    </ContextMenu>  
    

    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
                    ToolTipText ="{Binding ToolTipText}" DoubleClickCommand="{Binding}"
                    ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}"
                    IconSource="{Binding ToolTipStatus, 
                    Converter={StaticResource ServiceControllerWorkerStatusToIconConverter}
                    , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >

        <!-- Original Not Working-->
        <!-- self-assign a data context (could also be done programmatically) -->
        <!--<tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <local:NotifyIconViewModel/>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>-->

        <!-- 2nd try Not Working-->
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:NotifyIconViewModel}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                    <interface:ServiceControllerWorker />
                </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>

    </tb:TaskbarIcon>


</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
    class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper 
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainerBuilder(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.ConfigureContainerBuilder(builder);

            builder.RegisterType<ServiceControllerWorker>().As<IServiceControllerWorker>().SingleInstance();
    
        }
    }
```

**NotifyIconViewModel.cs (Constructor only)**

```
 public NotifyIconViewModel(IServiceControllerWorker ServiceControllerWorker)
 {    
      _serviceControllerWorker = ServiceControllerWorker;
  }
```

Comment: The `Notifyicon` package example contains `Window` declaration as container for icon. Try to do the same and set the `DataContext` in code behind. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948542/the-type-does-not-include-any-accessible-constructors-wpf-no-window-application) article shows different ways to instantiate a VM

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i will look into the example but the article you mentioned is this question

Comment: The way you are instantiating the view model you are making dependency injection and therefore Autofac redundant (at least in this case).

Comment: Let me update my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because you are setting the `ObjectDataProvider` instance to the `DataContext`

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type local:NotifyIconViewModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <interface:ServiceControllerWorker />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
```

instead of the *value* of the `ObjectDataProvider`.
Declare the provider in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>    
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ViewModelProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:NotifyIconViewModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <interface:ServiceControllerWorker />
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And bind it to the `DataContext`:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelProvider}}" />
```

The binding will make the provider to instantiate the provided instance.

But since you are creating the instance with the help of `ObjectDataProvider` you made the Autofac container or dependency injection redundant. If you want to use dependency injection, you must let Autofac create the instances. This requires the application to be started manually and to rewrite the `MainWindow` or the hosting `Window` of the `TaskbarIcon` to use composition:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotifyIconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "NotifyIcon",
      typeof(TaskbarIcon),
      typeof(Window),
      new PropertyMetadata(default(TaskbarIcon)));

    public TaskbarIcon NotifyIcon { get { return (TaskbarIcon) GetValue(MainWindow.NotifyIconProperty); } set { SetValue(MainWindow.NotifyIconProperty, value); } }

    public MainWindow(TaskbarIcon taskbarIcon, INotifyIconViewModel notifyIconDataContext, IViewModel dataContext)
    {
        this.notifyIcon = taskbarIcon;     
        this.notifyIcon.DataContext = notifyIconDataContext;   
        this.DataContext = dataContext;      
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow.xaml bind the property to a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<Window>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=NotifyIcon} />
</Window>
```

Then configure the Autofac container:

```
class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper 
{
    public Container ConfigureContainerBuilder()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<ServiceControllerWorker>().As<IServiceControllerWorker>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<NotifyIconViewModel>().As<INotifyIconViewModel>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<TaskbarIcon>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().SingleInstance();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then bootstrap the application:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        var container = bootstrapper.ConfigureContainerBuilder();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();         
    }
}
```

This way you got rid of the `ObjectDataProvider`, since you are using Autofac instead.

Comment: how can i set <Window.Resources>  in ResourceDictionary?

Comment: It was just an example to show, that you have to add the `ObjectDataProvider` to a `ResourceDictionary`. Just add it to any `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: I'm now getting **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** error at ObjectDataProvider, I think its because that somewhere in my ViewModel I'm calling `new PopUpWindow();`

Comment: Yes, check your view model. Besides this I can guarantee you that it will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196192/discussion-between-styx-and-bioniccode).

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to use dependency injection. The example assumes that you have a view model interface 'INotifyIconViewModel'.